# Android Support library Gradle sync error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

Why I get following error?
I wanted to update my support libraries from Android and searched alot but didn't find anything appropriate to my problem.

[image: Android Studio Gradle sync error]

here is my app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ussystech.calc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

}
```

Comment: ever try to click **Install Repository and sync project**?

Comment: Update Android Support Repository and Android Support Library in your SDK Manager

Answer (score 1):

Update `Android Support Repository` and `Android Support Library` in your Android SDK manager.

By the way, I recommend you to use `com.android.support:design:23.1.0` instead of `com.android.support:design:23.0.1`

Comment: "By the way, I recommend you to use com.android.support:design:23.1.0 instead of com.android.support:design:23.0.1"
Thats all my question is about!:)

Answer (score 0):

Providing that "Install Repository and sync project" doesn't work I would ensure you're properly connected to the internet. The organization I work for does funny stuff with certificates which break SSL which can result in this error you are receiving. If that's the case, open Android SDK Manager, go to Preferences/Settings, and then check "Force https://". You may also need to clear the download cache which is located just above that check box.